# Lookup & Reference in a Calendar on Excel

Tags: excel, reference, calendar, lookup

I'm looking for ways to put the name of the Customer into a calendar corresponding to the table at the left, as shown in the image below.
I tried with References and Lookup functions but I have not found a way to do it.
Any recommendation to do it with VBA or Functions?

[image]

Comment: I don't think so, because in some point will have months with blanks spaces, or what do you mean with row per customer?

Comment: In the image was just an example to explain it better, but in reality the number of customers may vary, they may be 5 to 100 and calendar would not be one below the other, they would be next to each other, so that it can extend down customers if necessary.